# Error during R package install from Github

Tags: r

I need autoEDA package from github:

```
install.packages('devtools')
library(devtools)
devtools::install_github("XanderHorn/autoEDA")
library(autoEDA)
```

Error message appeared like this:

```
Error in curl::curl_download(input, tmpFile <- tempfile(), mode = "wb",  : 
Could not resolve host: raw.githubusercontent.com
```

anyone knows?

Comment: Have you tried opening your console and `ping raw.githubusercontent.com`? This download using `devtools` just worked for me. If your internet connection is good you may want to edit your post and include your `sessionInfo()`. Thanks :)